# Is it possible to generalize the pV-term in the definition of enthalpy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

My physics textbook defines enthalpy as $H=U+pV$, but I was wondering: Is it possible to generalize the $pV$-term so that the enthalpy definition can also be applied directly to systems described by state variables other than $p$ and $V$?

In other words: Let's consider a general system described by an intensive variable $y$, and an extensive variable $X$. Can the enthalpy of this system be written as $H=U-yX$, or some other general expression using $y$ and $X$, or does the definition have to contain $p$ and $V$, regardless of the description of the system?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can generalize to include, for instance, magnetic effects (such as fcc vs bcc phases in iron).

Comment: You are looking for the [Legendre transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation)

Comment: Thanks! So I take it H=U-yX is correct for a system described solely by y and X, right? The Legendre transform seems like it can resolve this and many related question, but it seems a bit too advanced for me to use efficiently at the time being. I'm sure I'll put it to good use in the future, though.